# Get other user's outlook tasks with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I am developing an application which can read and write user's outlook tasks. I'm able to read the tasks assigned to my user id with the below API.

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/admin@mycompany.com/outlook/tasks

When I try to read other user's tasks by providing the userPrincipalName I'm getting 403 error.

Request: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/support@mycompany.com/outlook/tasks

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "05fab540-3638-4b61-95ef-f2470539f385",
        "date": "2020-08-17T07:25:06"
    }
}
}
```

Please let me know whether it is possible to read other user's tasks.

Answer (score 0):

To read the tasks of multiple users you will nee to use a Application permissions and not Delegated https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts#microsoft-graph-permissions

This is to stop users from accessing data that belongs to other users.

Comment: But the Task object is not available under the Application permissions

Comment: Well, TIL. Looks like it's under review at the moment: https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/20160895-add-permissions-tasks-read-all-or-tasks-readwrite